# How to use Tensorflow Serving restful API on multiple named inputs estimator model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

**Tensorflow version**: 1.14.0

**Tensorflow serving version**: 1.14.0

---

### Description

The saved estimator model has multiple named inputs, whose keys are `input_1`, `input_2`... And these inputs are tf.feature_column.*, I saved serving model using codes below, where `feature_columns` is a list of inputs:

```py
estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(features, 1000), steps=100)
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
        tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))
estimator.export_saved_model("from_estimator/", serving_input_fn)
```

After model saved, I use `saved_model_cli` show the inputs and outputs of this model:

`saved_model_cli show --dir /from_estimator/1572335377/ --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default`

which **print**:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['examples'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1)
      name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['logits'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 100)
      name: MatMul_1:0
  outputs['probabilities'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 100)
      name: Softmax:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

**Note** that the inputs are not the expected keys `input_1` and `input_2`, but `examples`. Confusing about it !!

Whatever, I using `saved_model_cli` run the model locally by:

`saved_model_cli run --dir from_estimator/1572335377/ --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default --input_examples "examples=[{'input_1': [1],'input_2': [1]}]"`

And it gave the right outputs.

### Question

I deployed the model using docker image of tensorflow serving, and tried to get the outputs from restful api. I've tried the request format as follow, but all of them failed:

1. `curl -d '{"instances": [{"input_1": [1],"input_2": [1]}]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/from_estimator:predict`, it gave the `wrong key of input` error.
2. `curl -d '{"instances": [{"examples": {"input_1": [1],"input_2": [1]}}]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/from_estimator:predict`, it gave `Invalid argument: JSON Value:  not formatted correctly for base64 data` error.
3. `curl -d '{"instances": [{"examples": "{\"input_1\": [1],\"input_2\": [1]}"}]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/from_estimator:predict`, it gave `couldn't parse` error.

So how to set the multiple named inputs properly? thanks~

Comment: Hi. Is your issue resolved now? Else, Since the Data Type of the Inputs from the SignatureDef is `DT_String`, you can try passing base 64 encoded strings as Inputs like shown below:

{
  "instances": [
                  {"b64": "iVBORw"},
                  {"b64": "pT4rmN"},
                  {"b64": "w0KGg2"}
                 ]
}

Comment: i have the same issue, any progress on this question?

Comment: by the way, your signature shows that there is only one input argument... Otherwise you have had `inputs["bla"]` and later `inputs["blo"]`.